# All elements rendering twice in Kivy + KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have started building a simple app using Kivy (and am in the process of moving over to KivyMD for aesthetic purposes) and have come across an issue where all of the elements I'm rendering to screen are rendering twice: The first time they are static and uninteractable and the second time are the interactable ones over the top. Im working with some ScrollViews with Buttons in them and when I scroll the buttons underneath are visible. There is also Labels with text that I update, these still show the default text underneath them.

[screenshot of double rendering elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD5gi.png)

main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty

class MagnateCalcApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("magnatecalc.kv")

class CalcWindow(Screen):
    current_value = NumericProperty(100)
    current_price = NumericProperty(1)
    pricelabel = ObjectProperty(None)
    valuelabel = ObjectProperty(None)
    money = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self):
        if self.current_price != 1:
            val = float(self.current_price)/1000
            self.pricelabel.text = "Price: " + str(val) + "M"
        if self.current_value != 100:
            self.valuelabel.text = "Multiplier: " + str(self.current_value)
        if self.current_price != 1 and self.current_value != 100:
            val = (float(self.current_value) * float(self.current_price))/1000
            print(val)
            self.money.text = "Value: " + str(val) + "M"

class RentWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MagnateCalcApp().run()
```

magnatecalc.kv (usually has quite a lot of buttons in the ScrollView but the majority of these have been removed for readability)

```
WindowManager:
    CalcWindow:
    RentWindow:

<Button>:
    font_size:35
    size_hint:0.5,0.5

<CalcWindow>:
    name: "Calc"
    current_value: 100
    current_price: 1
    pricelabel: pricelabel
    valuelabel: valuelabel
    money: money

    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text:""
            pos_hint:{"x":0, "top":1}
            size_hint_y:0.15
            size_hint_x:0.05

        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_y:False
            do_scroll_x:True
            pos_hint:{"x":1, "top":1}
            size_hint_y:0.15
            GridLayout: # here i want a scrollview
                id: price
                rows: 1
                size_hint_x: None
                width: self.minimum_width
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"300K"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_price = 300
                        root.update()
                    group:"price"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"400K"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_price = 400
                        root.update()
                    group:"price"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"500K"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_price = 500
                        root.update()
                    group:"price"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"600K"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_price = 600
                        root.update()
                    group:"price"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"700K"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_price = 700
                        root.update()
                    group:"price"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"800K"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_price = 800
                        root.update()
                    group:"price"
             
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_y:True
            do_scroll_x:False
            pos_hint:{"x":0, "top":0}
            size_hint_x:0.075
            GridLayout: # here i want a scrollview
                id: multiplier
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"2"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_value = 2
                        root.update()
                    group:"multiplier"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"3"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_value = 3
                        root.update()
                    group:"multiplier"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"4"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_value = 4
                        root.update()
                    group:"multiplier"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"5"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_value = 5
                        root.update()
                    group:"multiplier"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"6"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_value = 6
                        root.update()
                    group:"multiplier"
                ToggleButton:
                    text:"7"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    on_press:
                        root.current_value = 7
                        root.update()
                    group:"multiplier"
               
        GridLayout:
            rows:2
            pos_hint:{"x":1, "top":0}

            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                Label:
                    id:pricelabel
                    text:"Price: "
                    font_size:50
                Label:
                    id:valuelabel
                    text:"Multiplier: "
                    font_size:50
            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                Label:
                    id:money
                    text:"Value: "
                    font_size:90
                    size_hint_x:1
                    pos_hint:{"x":0, "top":0}

                Button:
                    text:"<- Rent"
                    pos_hint:{"x":1, "top":0}
                    size_hint: 0.25,0.25
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "Rent"
                        root.manager.transition.direction="right"

<RentWindow>:
    name: "Rent"
    Button:
        text:"Go Back ->"
        on_release:
            app.root.current="Calc"
            root.manager.transition.direction="left"
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing in my .py that would cause this? This issue appeared when I started switching over to KivyMD but I have since reverted those changes to try and get back to the original functionality and I can't so have clearly broken something along the way.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. What OS are you running? What versions of kivy, kivymd, and python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Your kv file is being loaded twice, once explicitly by you with `Builder.load_file` and once automatically because it has the same name as your app class.

The simplest solution is to skip the manual load and just delete your `build` method.

Comment: And how are we supposed to do that and also how are we supposed to build our app without `build` method ??

Comment: @YashasviBhatt There is nothing wrong with using the build method, this answer is about the specific incorrect build method in the question.

Comment: That's why I am asking can you tell me how to do it without using the build method since I am also having the same problem and I want to get rid of it, when I remove the build method the screen becomes completely blank

Comment: Post a specific question then, giving a minimal runnable example

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and I figured out how to build correctly the app to stop duplicate the items.
In kivymd this is the correct way to build the app:

```
class MagnateCalcApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return super().build()
```

I don't know how but it recognises the correct kivy file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same thing occur after I was using pyinstaller to create a distribution.  The build and dist directories created by the pyinstaller process contained copies of my .kv files.  This was causing all the visual elements to appear multiple times depending on how many copies of the files were present in other directories.

Moving or deleting these directories solved the issue for me.